# Woocommerce product reviews do not show

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have built my online shop on Wordpress and using Woocommerce plugin, theme is Ellie. Reviews are enabled and I am able to add a review as an Admin in backend and it becomes visible in frontend.

[Review added in Admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPcND.jpg)

However, when I try to add a review on product page like a customer, after submitting the review nothing happens. I do not see the review anywhere in backend nor does it appear in the frontend.

Please help!

https://senjacosmetics.com/product/sleek-cheek-deep-cleansing-oil/

Comment: Certainly because the review need to be approved by the admin. Please remember that StackOverFlow is about coding and not about settings: *"Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow **unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming**"*.

Comment: Well, no comment have appeared to be approved.